# Why do I get power from line through load's neutral?

Tags: receptacle, gfci

I replaced a GFCI outlet.  The old one was good, but I wanted one with USB sockets.    After removing the old outlet, I double checked the wiring.  One black wire was hot and the other was not.  So far, so good.   But, I found that the hot black line wire would show 120 volts on a voltmeter through either of the two neutral wires.   A connectivity test shows that the two neutrals are *not* tied together, nor is either tied to ground.  So, that's good.  But, why does the hot line work with either neutral?  Does this mean that the load's neutral line connects back to the fusebox?  Is that normal practice?

Comment: With both neutrals disconnected/floating in the air, only the one connected to the panel should show 120v on a simple A to B to C receptacle circuit, with nothing plugged in.  Lights added in might change this.

Comment: Are there any other dead outlets now that you've disconnected this one? If so, one of those neutrals carried power on to that outlet. Are you _certain_ that there's only one source of power into this junction box? It's always possible (for a wide variety of reasons, some of which don't meet code) that there would be 2 circuits in one box.

Comment: Sounds like a faulty or misapplied tester, or the downline neutral has a ground fault.

Comment: Yes, there's only one source of power.  Two different jackets with three wires each and with only the bare grounds tied together.  I tested all combinations while disconnected and the only voltage seen was one of the two black wires, but that wire worked with either neutral.   Yes, there are downstream outlets on the load side.  I didn't check them, but if something downstream had a ground fault, wouldn't I have seen connectivity between ground and neutral in the box I was working on?

Comment: Some digital voltmeters have such a high impedance that they will show 120V between hot and almost anything that is not also hot.  What happens when you put one probe on hot and touch the other to the back of your hand?  (Back of hand is a safety trick; there shouldn't be enough current to shock you, but if there is, your hand will flinch away and break the circuit - the opposite of gripping the probe and finding you can't let go.). If you get 120V, it may be the meter.  What happens if you reconnect the load side of the new GFCI and power up?